# NO-OP blocks in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I write academic articles with org mode. Sometimes I'd like to keep things clustered in no-op blocks, just so I can identify them later. An example would be reviewer comments or changes:

```
* Methods

We did a bit of this and that.

#+begin_revision
# Reviewer said our methods weren't clear enough
In this we collected data from N participants...
In that we analysed the data as described in X.
#+end_revision
```

I don't want drawers because I don't want to keep things hidden per default. I'd prefer to have a no-op block, whereby its content goes to export as if the block didn't exist at all. The advantage is that If I ever went back to the manuscript years later, I'd still have this "meta" block information in there.

I know I could use the `:ignore:` tag and have an extra heading, but I feel these comments don't really belong in the document hierarchy.

Are there NO-OP blocks? Or what would be the best way to implement them?

Comment: What about [comment blocks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-Lines.html)?

Comment: Thanks, learned something new. Yet, comment blocks are not exported. I want to group pieces of text that should be exported and visible, yet not part of the document hierarchy.

Comment: What you describe looks to me just like a comment, e.g., `# begin_revision` and `# end_revision` without the + sign. such that orgmode does not recognize it. It is only your own convention.

Comment: Here's how you could define them: `(defblock revision nil nil "A no-op block." contents)` ---this now just works when https://alhassy.github.io/org-special-block-extras/ is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an unknown block is called a *special block*.

In org 9.0.3, section 11.8 of documentation ("Special blocks") says:

> Each export back-end decides if they should be exported, and how.
>   When the block is ignored, its contents are still exported, as if the
>   opening and closing block lines were not there.

In section 12.15 (Exporting/Advanced configuration) the use of filters is described:

> Filters are lists of functions applied on a specific part of the output
>   from a given back-end.  More explicitly, each time a back-end transforms
>   an Org object or element into another language, all functions within a
>   given filter type are called in turn on the string produced.  The string
>   returned by the last function will be the one used in the final output.
>
> There are filters sets for each type of element or object, for plain
>   text, for the parse tree, for the export options and for the final
>   output.  They are all named after the same scheme:
>   ‘org-export-filter-TYPE-functions’, where ‘TYPE’ is the type targeted by
>   the filter.

*special block* is one such type, so you could do:

```el
(defun my-export-no-special-block (text backend info)
  "Do not export the content of special blocks."
  "")

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-special-block-functions
         'my-export-no-special-block)
```

Note this will turn off exporting of all special blocks (not just *revision*), for all backends.